# Workshop dates on a CV

Tags: united-states, job-search, cv, job

I am currently working on my CV (I am looking to apply to local community colleges as an English Comp and ESL Instructor) and a coworker recommended that I include the workshops I present for my job on my CV.

I am a writing tutor for a community college so every semester I get scheduled to present about 15-20 workshops to students. The subject of the workshops vary. For example,  I present workshops with the college's library on how to do research, and I also present workshops on grammar, essay organization, overcoming writing anxiety, etc. I have created power points for most of these workshops, but not all, and I have been presenting these various workshops for a few years now.

After looking at others' questions about CVs and workshops, I created a heading title "Workshops Facilitated" but since these workshop get presented a few times a semester since Fall 2020, I am not sure if I should just list the semesters I present them, or should I be specific with the dates since I do have the schedules.

And, should I even put these workshops on my CV?  I just graduated with my M.A and I feel like these workshops are valuable, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Those workshops seem directly relevant to the job. The fact that you do, and what is covered, seem far more important than any exact dates. So, I'd put it as part of your work experience as a writing tutor.

Answer (score 1):

Since the workshops are an activity that shows your qualification for the job for which you are applying, they should be on your CV. However, you need to summarize them. For example, you can list the topic together with a list of dates.